Service worker Cache updates - To intercept the service worker request, until we click "OK" to pop-up, hash values shouldn't update into CacheStorage?
I have tried intercepting the service worker request, since it's updating the cache storage on navigation whenever there's new deployment or changes is available in application even the changes started serving to UI before the user's agree for a pop-up of version updates.
I want to block/intercept the service worker request until unless i agree for version update pop-up then the latest hash values should add to Cache storage.
I have tried with cache bursting, even the hash values are added to cache storage before we agree for version updates.
 `this.http.get("../../../ngsw.json").subscribe((ngswConfig: any) =>{
        console.log("Calling the ngsw-json file",ngswConfig);
        const currentTimestamp = ngswConfig.timestamp;
        console.log("CurrentTimestamp",currentTimestamp);
        const cachedTimestamp = localStorage.getItem("ngsw-timestamp");
        console.log("CachedTimeStamp value",cachedTimestamp);
        if(currentTimestamp != cachedTimestamp){
            console.log("if loop is passed");
            localStorage.setItem("ngsw-timestamp", currentTimestamp);
            console.log("call is going to version Detection");
           ..............
           ..............
            Here i'm showing a pop-up once we find the mismatch in the ngsw timestamp,       like there's version detection/update is available to proceed - Once user clicks "OK" then we have to add the latest hash values to cache storage.
           ..............
           ..............

            });`

